# What is the term for those yellow/orange boxes in public where you defecate?

Tags: terminology

Cubicles?? I can't seem to get the word on Google nor the picture. But I have seen them in the EU and US on movies.

Comment: You can urinate also, or if you are a woman, do other things. And they come in lots of colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you mean?

[image]

[Chemical Toilet](https://Chemical%20toilet)

> Chemical toilets are a type of portable toilet and are also known by various tradenames, such as Port-a-John and Porta-Potty (American English), Portaloo (British English),honey bucket, or sanican. The last two are the names of companies[4][5] and "Portaloo" is a British and European Community registered trade mark.[6]

Comment: Also "Johnny-on-the-spot", at least in North America

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, these are very often called 'portable toilets'. Sometimes 'chemical' is used. Just 'chemical toilet' on its own can refer to something my father called an 'Elsan' (a brand name) which is just the thing you sit on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Porta potty, that's word I was trying to get from backrooms of my brain!